# Convert model on Hugging Face website to CoreML

Tags: coreml, huggingface

I'm moving forward by reading the document here.

https://github.com/apple/ml-stable-diffusion#converting-models-to-coreml

But I am getting error in this category.

I found this solution on the internet, but I couldn't find how to switch to `diffusers` version `0.15.1`.

Solution: https://github.com/apple/ml-stable-diffusion/issues/173

**Converting Models to Core ML**

Step 1: Create a Python environment and install dependencies:

conda create -n coreml_stable_diffusion python=3.8 -y
conda activate coreml_stable_diffusion
cd /path/to/cloned/ml-stable-diffusion/repository
pip install -e .

I am running the above code one by one.

**1. conda create -n coreml_stable_diffusion python=3.8 -y**

[image]

**2. conda activate coreml_stable_diffusion**

[image]

**3. cd /path/to/cloned/ml-stable-diffusion/repository**

[image]

**4. pip install -e .**

[image]

**5. python -m python_coreml_stable_diffusion.torch2coreml --convert-unet --convert-text-encoder --convert-vae-decoder --convert-safety-checker -o < output-mlpackages-directory >**

[image]

Comment: Ufuk,  Can you check if your Python version is 3.8 or not? Additionally, you can clone specific versions of the diffusers with the following commands:

{git clone https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers.git --branch e753454}. Alternatively,  you can list all versions with {git tag -l} and then check out the specific version with {git checkout tags/v0.15.1}